# Distributing a LaTeX2e compiler in .NET application

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is there a way to wrap a LaTeX compiler with a .NET application, so that the wrapper can compile an output .tex file, and visualize the results?

Where can I get a compiler (For free, commercial?) that can be distributed via wrapping and run on the output .tex file?

It would have to be able to produce .dvi files from .tex files, and then display the .dvi results?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? (La)TeX is a large, complex beast, the result won't be at all portable (like .NET is). There are subsets (like MathJax) available.

Comment: It would be more effective to find one that compiles right to PDF – there are plenty of PDF tools for .NET. If you can find a TeX engine in .NET, you should be able to configure everything so that you can just move the entire TeX distribution with your component (huge!). Unless you want to get into a client/server situation, that is the *only* way this is going to work.

Comment: Note that your usage would have to comply with a number of different free software licences. Depending on which components you need, that might or might not include the GPL. This might all be fine, of course. Just something to be aware of. Note that LaTeX 2e is a *format* which, on its own, can't compile anything. You at least need an *engine* but, if you want to support arbitrary LaTeX source, you need all the packages and extras as well....

Comment: I would limit the packages required, since that would be fixed in the output .tex file.  (If users wanted other packages, then they're on their own).

Comment: Also, looked around and searched and this is not a simple task.  MikTek was not a user friendly package, so asking users to install that would be disastrous.  I will look for some web pages that process LaTeX (.tex) files to see what can be accomplished.  If there's a commercial redistributable, then acquiring that may ease some of the development effort and user feedback(issues).

Comment: By the way, Sean's suggestion for compiling to PDF is outstanding, since users wouldn't be able to do much with a .dvi file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can use components with open source licences I would use luatex (or xetex+xdvipdfmx) and generate tex files using system fonts via the fontspec and unicode-math packages.

That way you only need a very minimal tex distribution, with no fonts as you can use system fonts (eg assuming you are only using .NET on windows, not the linux/mono implementation you can use the system Cambria Math font for math).

So more or less you would only need the luatex binary, plus any packages that you use.

This would of course be using a system call rather than use pure .NET code throughout but porting to .NET is probably a lot of work and doesn't really gain much.